# Batch, Can i post my script to credit those who have assisted me?

Tags: batch-file

I've been using stack overflow as an unregistered user for about a year now. I want to post my IT scripts to give credit to those on stack overflow that has assisted me in its endeavor but I'm not entirely sure if I'm allowed to do that, as I have not seen anyone else post a program.

It's about 750 lines and I can probably reduce it by removing comments and unfinished sections.

Yes, I'm a newbie, thanks being supportive!

Comment: I don't think SO is the place for that. But you could always publish your code on a platform like gitlab/github/bitbucket and put links to the SO profiles of whoever helped you in the readme.

Comment: Well, i did that in the credits of my script and i wrote the credits to stack and the users i needed to credit in binary because i thought it would give it a little extra POW when it was translated ! I'll make an account for git hub right now. thanks joppich

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not the right place to share code, it's a question and answer site.